# Why does tabbar move a few pixels down when the app is coming back from background?

Tags: android, background, tabbar, shift

Here's the code:

public class MenuTabActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{

```
@Override   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_layout);

    TabHost tb = getTabHost();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = null;
    Intent intent = null;

    // My Profile tab
    intent = new Intent(this, MyProfileActivityGroup.class);

    View myProfileView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button_profil, null);
    spec = tb.newTabSpec("0").setIndicator(myProfileView).setContent(intent);
    tb.addTab(spec);

    // Driving tab
    intent = new Intent(this, DrivingActivityGroup.class);
    View drivingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button_conduite, null);
    spec = tb.newTabSpec("1").setIndicator(drivingView).setContent(intent);
    tb.addTab(spec);

    // Score Tab
    intent = new Intent(this, ScoreActivityGroup.class);
    View scoreView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button_score, null);
    spec = tb.newTabSpec("2").setIndicator(scoreView).setContent(intent);
    tb.addTab(spec);

    // Advices Tab
    intent = new Intent(this, AdvicesActivity.class);
    View advicesView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.button_conseils, null);
    spec = tb.newTabSpec("3").setIndicator(advicesView).setContent(intent);

    tb.addTab(spec);
    tb.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    Main.tabBar = tb;
    tb.setCurrentTab(0);
}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

    if (tabId.equals("2")){

        //refresh third tab
        ((ScoreActivityGroup)(getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabId))).getScoreActivity().updateView();
    }

    if (tabId.equals("1")){ //driving activity

        if (Utils.tabImage == null) {

            //create the static image of the tabbar here
            Bitmap tabImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(getTabHost().getTabWidget().getWidth(), getTabHost().getTabWidget().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            getTabHost().getTabWidget().draw(new Canvas(tabImage));
            Utils.tabImage = tabImage;
        }

        //load second "tab" Activity
        ((DrivingActivityGroup)(getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("1"))).startDrivingActivity();
    }

    if (!tabId.equals("2")){

        if (getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("2") != null){

            if (((ScoreActivityGroup)getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("2")).getCurrentActivity() instanceof ScoreDetailsActivity){

                //dismiss Conseil Dialog if it exists
                ((ScoreDetailsActivity)(((ScoreActivityGroup)getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("2")).getCurrentActivity())).dismissConseilDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This method starts an activity with a given animation (ex: bottom-top)
 * Used for info activities
 * 
 * This action is placed here because the animations are ignored if done
 * from child activities of the MenuTabActivity.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 * @param enterAnim
 * @param exitAnim
 * @param intentExtra
 */
public void startActivityWithOverridePendingTransition(Class<?> clazz, int enterAnim, int exitAnim, Integer intentExtra){
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, clazz);
    if ( intentExtra !=  null ){
        intent.putExtra("com.renault.Intent", intentExtra);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(enterAnim, exitAnim);
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    if (Main.monitoringHasStarted) {

        Main.DriveBusinessService.stopMonitoring();
        ScoringModelPojo.saveToBundle(getApplicationContext());
    }

    Main.monitoringHasStarted = false;

    SettingsModel.saveToBundle(getApplicationContext());
}
```

}
`

Here's the tabwidget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_weight = "1"/>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background = "@color/grayFond" 
            android:layout_weight = "0"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Did any of you come across the issue mentioned in the title?

Comment: Wat do you want to know?

Comment: the issue is clearly stated in the title. Where's your confusion?

Comment: Initially u dint posted ur code so only

Comment: code posted as well. But the issue is most likely inside the layout xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. It must be a bug in there. In the manifest file I had no status bar and full screen. When introducing the status bar back into the screen, (NO FULLSCREEN) it worked as it should. Maybe this helps someone.

PS. This should be filed as a bug with ANDROID. (tested in 2.1)